# Why can't I plot from .csv file

Tags: csv, plot, latex, tikz, pgfplots

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{escalon_de_tension_de_flanco_descendente_5V.csv}
t,A,B
0.0438,2.05,4.92
0.0538,2.05,4.96
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=t, y=A, col sep=comma] {escalon_de_tension_de_flanco_descendente_5V.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The message I receive is:

[Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WCfC.png)

[Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOmK3.png)

[Part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulBcH.png)

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

LOG FILE : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.4.19) 18 MAY 2022 07:53 entering extended mode \write18 enabled. %&-line parsing enabled. **./main.tex (main.tex LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2022-02-24> (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.cls Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan dalone (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75. ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead. (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests )) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex \XKV@toks=\toks16 \XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex)) \XKV@depth=\count185 File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA) )) \sa@internal=\count186 \c@sapage=\count187 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.cfg File: standalone.cfg 2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalon e' class ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count188 \c@section=\count189 \c@subsection=\count190 \c@subsubsection=\count191 \c@paragraph=\count192 \c@subparagraph=\count193 \c@figure=\count194 \c@table=\count195 \abovecaptionskip=\skip47 \belowcaptionskip=\skip48 \bibindent=\dimen138 ) \sa@box=\box50 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgfplots\pgfplots.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.revision.tex) Package: pgfplots 2021/05/15 v1.18.1 Data Visualization (1.18.1) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC) ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration ) Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107. (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex )) \Gin@req@height=\dimen139 \Gin@req@width=\dimen140 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex \pgfutil@everybye=\toks18 \pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen141 \pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen142 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def \pgfutil@abb=\box51 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex) Package: pgfrcs 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) )) Package: pgf 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex Package: pgfsys 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex \pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19 \pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex \pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21 )) \pgf@x=\dimen143 \pgf@y=\dimen144 \pgf@xa=\dimen145 \pgf@ya=\dimen146 \pgf@xb=\dimen147 \pgf@yb=\dimen148 \pgf@xc=\dimen149 \pgf@yc=\dimen150 \pgf@xd=\dimen151 \pgf@yd=\dimen152 \w@pgf@writea=\write3 \r@pgf@reada=\read2 \c@pgf@counta=\count196 \c@pgf@countb=\count197 \c@pgf@countc=\count198 \c@pgf@countd=\count199 \t@pgf@toka=\toks22 \t@pgf@tokb=\toks23 \t@pgf@tokc=\toks24 \pgf@sys@id@count=\count266 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg File: pgf.cfg 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ) Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count267 \pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count268 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) )) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration ) Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227. Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by` cmy0' on input line 1352. Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by` rgb' on input line 1356. Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368. Package xcolor Info: Model` HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370. Package xcolor Info: Model` Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371. Package xcolor Info: Model` tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372. Package xcolor Info: Model` HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373. Package xcolor Info: Model` Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374. Package xcolor Info: Model` wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375. ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex Package: pgfcore 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex \pgfmath@dimen=\dimen153 \pgfmath@count=\count269 \pgfmath@box=\box52 \pgfmath@toks=\toks25 \pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks26 \pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks27 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.co de.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code. tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmeti cs.code.tex))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex \c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count270 )) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgf@picminx=\dimen154 \pgf@picmaxx=\dimen155 \pgf@picminy=\dimen156 \pgf@picmaxy=\dimen157 \pgf@pathminx=\dimen158 \pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen159 \pgf@pathminy=\dimen160 \pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen161 \pgf@xx=\dimen162 \pgf@xy=\dimen163 \pgf@yx=\dimen164 \pgf@yy=\dimen165 \pgf@zx=\dimen166 \pgf@zy=\dimen167 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.t ex File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgf@path@lastx=\dimen168 \pgf@path@lasty=\dimen169 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen170 \pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen171 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgfpic=\box53 \pgf@hbox=\box54 \pgf@layerbox@main=\box55 \pgf@picture@serial@count=\count271 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.te x File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgflinewidth=\dimen172 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code .tex File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgf@pt@x=\dimen173 \pgf@pt@y=\dimen174 \pgf@pt@temp=\dimen175 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code. tex File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgfarrowsep=\dimen176 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgf@max=\dimen177 \pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count272 \pgf@shadingcount=\count273 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56 )) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.te x File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen178 \pgf@nodesepend=\dimen179 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) )) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex Package: pgffor 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex) \pgffor@iter=\dimen180 \pgffor@skip=\dimen181 \pgffor@stack=\toks28 \pgffor@toks=\toks29 )) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex Package: tikz 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code. tex File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgf@plot@mark@count=\count274 \pgfplotmarksize=\dimen182 ) \tikz@lastx=\dimen183 \tikz@lasty=\dimen184 \tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen185 \tikz@lastysaved=\dimen186 \tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen187 \tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen188 \tikzleveldistance=\dimen189 \tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen190 \tikz@figbox=\box58 \tikz@figbox@bg=\box59 \tikz@tempbox=\box60 \tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61 \tikztreelevel=\count275 \tikznumberofchildren=\count276 \tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count277 \tikz@fig@count=\count278 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) \pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count279 \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count280 \pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count281 ) \tikz@expandcount=\count282 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra rytopaths.code.tex File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotscore.code.tex \t@pgfplots@toka=\toks30 \t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks31 \t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks32 \pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen191 \c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count283 \c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count284 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/sys\pgfplotssysgeneric.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\pgfplotslibrary.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib\pgfplotsoldpgfsupp _loader.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsutil.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsliststructu re.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsliststructu reext.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsarray.code. tex \c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count285 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsmatrix.code .tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable\pgfplotstableshared.code .tex \c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count286 \t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks33 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsdeque.code. tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsbinary.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsbinary.data.code.tex )) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsutil.verb.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshadi ng.code.tex \c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count287 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/sys\pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshadin g.pgfsys-pdftex.def))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotscolormap.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotscolor.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.tex))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.scaling.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.markers.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsticks.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.paths.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra rydecorations.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex \pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen192 \pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen193 \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen194 \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen195 \pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen196 \pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count288 \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen197 \pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen198 ) \tikz@lib@dec@box=\box62 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra rydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations\pgflibrarydecora tions.pathmorphing.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra rydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations\pgflibrarydecora tions.pathreplacing.code.tex)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\tikzlibrarypgfplots.contourl ua.code.tex) \pgfplots@numplots=\count289 \pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen199 \pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen256 \pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen257 \pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen258 \pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen259 \pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen260 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra ryplotmarks.code.tex File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a) ))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries\tikzlibraryexter nal.code.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO ) (C:\Users\Montanelli\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO) ) (C:\Users\Montanelli\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO) ) Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available. Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available. Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found. ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac kage with kernel methods ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzexter nalshared.code.tex)) \openout3 =` main.auxlock'. (C:\Users\Montanelli\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/filecontents\filecontents .sty Package: filecontents 2019/09/20 v1.5 Create an external file from within a LaT eX document Package filecontents Warning: This package is obsolete. Disabling it and (filecontents) passing control to the filecontents environment (filecontents) defined by the LaTeX kernel. ) LaTeX Info: File `escalon_de_tension_de_flanco_descendente_5V.csv' already exis ts on the system. Not generating it from this source. (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX) \l__color_backend_stack_int=\count290 \l__pdf_internal_box=\box63 ) (main.aux) \openout1 =` main.aux'. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 35. (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] \scratchcounter=\count291 \scratchdimen=\dimen261 \scratchbox=\box64 \nofMPsegments=\count292 \nofMParguments=\count293 \everyMPshowfont=\toks34 \MPscratchCnt=\count294 \MPscratchDim=\dimen262 \MPnumerator=\count295 \makeMPintoPDFobject=\count296 \everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks35 ) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4 85. (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX )) Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}). \openout3 =` main.auxlock'. ===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjo b{main}\input{main}"' ======== runsystem(pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}")...executed. \openout3 = `main.auxlock'. ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{m ain}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'main-figure0' (expec ted one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system c alls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also name d 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'main-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to t ypeset the picture. See the tikz package documentation for explanation. Type H  for immediate help. ... l.63 \end{tikzpicture} This error message was generated by an \errmessage command, so I can't give any explicit help. Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by order and method. PGFPlots: reading {escalon_de_tension_de_flanco_descendente_5V.csv} PGFPlots: reading {escalon_de_tension_de_flanco_descendente_5V.csv} Runaway definition? -> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]. \pgfplotslistpushbackglobal ...e \t@pgfplots@tokb \the \t@pgfplots@toka } l.63 \end{tikzpicture} If you really absolutely need more capacity, you can ask a wizard to enlarge me. Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: 23097 strings out of 478582 617674 string characters out of 2854144 3000001 words of memory out of 3000000 40925 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 99i,2n,103p,729b,1495s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: I have positive and negative values in a .csv file which consists of three columns and 200 rows

Comment: Please check if you are compiling with shell-escape enabled. If this does not help, please add a compilable [mre] to your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I don't know if I'm compiling with shell-escape enabled. Could you tell me how to know that?

Comment: @el_maxx Can you share the first couple of lines of your .log file? Can you also tell us which latex editor you are using?

Comment: I edited my post to include the log file. I use TexMaker

Comment: Please add the first few line of the .log file, not the error message. It should start with something like `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.5.13)  17 MAY 2022 00:39
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.`

Comment: ... anyway, the problem is most likely the missing shell-escape. See here for instructions how to enable it with texmaker and miktex https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236648/36296

Comment: I tried enabling shell escape by adding the --enable-write18 option to pdflatex options. It still does not work. Here is the log file:
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.4.19) 16 MAY 2022 19:57
entering extended mode
\write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.

Comment: @el_maxx That looks good. Can you please share the complete .log file you get from the code in your question (as text and not images)?

Comment: (@el_maxx ... and please ping me with an @ and my username so I get notified of your replies)

Comment: @el_maxx Thanks! This looks good. Can you now show `main-figure0.log` (if possible including line breaks in a code block)

Comment: Stack overflow does not allow me to do paste so much code. I leave the .log file for downloading. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HrauRg8Z3zLfppEb0_Nbb4FG_k43HMaD/view?usp=sharing @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz